# Привязка поведения одного компонента к событию другого

Tags: html, css

Нужно, чтобы при получении input`ом фокуса появлялся список из div с помощью css.

```css
.list {
  display: none;
}

.search:hover .list{
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:9999;
}
```

```html
<input class="search"/>

<div class="list">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.list {
  display: none;
}

.search:focus + .list{
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:9999;
}
```

```html
<input class="search"/>

<div class="list">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
    
</div>
```